# Java CircularArrayQueue isEmpty method

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to implement a CircularArrayQueue and my method isEmpty() is returning false when the queue isn't populated. Can you point out my error?

```
public CircularArrayQueue(int size)
{
    array = new Integer[size];
    front = rear = 0;
}

... code omitted 

// returns the number of elements in the queue
@Override
public int noItems() 
{   
    return array.length - getCapacityLeft();
}

// returns true if the queue is empty
@Override
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return noItems() == 0;
}

//returns the number of available spots in the queue before a resize needs to be done
public int getCapacityLeft()
{
    return (array.length - rear + front)%array.length;
}
```

Comment: you posted the same question yesterday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return (array.length - rear + front)%array.length;
```

The above code, when array **size** is **0**, `getCapacityLeft` will throw `ArithmeticException`. for not enable divide by **zero**.

Answer (score 1):

When the queue is initialised, front and rear are both zero.

```
public int getCapacityLeft()
{
    return (array.length - rear + front)%array.length;
}
```

So `getCapacityLeft` returns `(array.length + 0)%array.length` which is zero.

You need to calculate the number of items correctly, taking into account how you manage the difference between a full buffer and an empty buffer - it seems that in both cases you are using rear == front. Decide how you will tell the difference and then you can write a getCapacityLeft which returns array.length if the buffer is empty and zero if it is full.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public int getCapacityLeft(){

return array.length - Math.abs(front - rear) + 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    if(front == -1 && rear == -1)
         return ture;
    else
         return false;
```

Comment: so... `return (front == -1 && rear == -1)`